# NuGet Fails to Update

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I am in VS 2022 and I have a project that I need to update.  I have a reference to a version `0.10.871` of one of my packages that lives on a custom NuGet feed in Azure DevOps.  It's not been updated for a while and this version dropped off of the history so it's not available anymore in my feed - latest version is `0.10.903`.  I got a new machine so it's not cached anymore.  Now when I try to do a NuGet restore I get this message:

> An error occurred while trying to restore packages: Unable to find version '0.10.871'...

and then it goes on to say the different places it looked.

That's fine, but then I try to go to that package and I see the updated version listed, but when I try to install the updated version it just things for a few seconds and then gives me the same message.  I've tried this with NuGet set to the custom feed where it lives and to 'All' with the same result.

So how do I get the updated version if the current version doesn't exist anymore and it wants that current version in order to install the updated version??

Comment: Rather than upgrade, have you tried removing the old version and then adding the new version instead?

Comment: Yes it won't even remove it without giving the same error.

Comment: In that case then, you should just be able to manually update the nuget reference manually. Depending on the project type it'll either be in the project file (.csproj) or packages.config.

Comment: I'm guessing that your project uses packages.config, and not PackageReference, otherwise I don't think NuGet would need the packages to be restored inorder to upgrade or uninstall. With packages.config, NuGet needs to know the old package version's contents, to know how to remove all references from the csproj.  You can hand edit the packages.config to remove the package, but you'll also need to search the csproj for all references to the package and remove potentially multiple references to the packages (dlls, props/targets imports).

Comment: Ok thank you!  I was able to manually update packages.config and the .csproj files to the new version and it worked.  I was able to update and build, etc.  If someone wants to make that an answer I will accept.

Comment: @sfaust Hi , I posted an answer, if you have a better answer, you could post it and mark it as the answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned you are using Azure DevOps feed and the version has been dropped off, then the issue you encountered is expected.

## First, from the Azure DevOps side, there are two situation.

**1, Unlist.**

If the version was unlisted, just relist it again and then you will be able to use it.

**2, Delete**

If the version was been deleted, then by default the version will be in soft-deleted status for 30 days, during the soft-deleted days, you could restore the version in the Recycle Bin:

[image]

after that, the version will be able to use again.

But if the time is more than 30 days, the deleted version will be unable to be restored again, the data is permanently removed from the database at this time.

---

## Second, from the client side

If the version in Azure DevOps feed is unable to be used again, then as others said, you could use .csproj and packages.config to use other available versions.

Here are the official document of those files:

[PackageReference in project files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files?source=recommendations)

[packages.config reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/packages-config)